# How to autoplay mp4 in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, twitter, mp4

I am learning with the Twitter API and am trying to load their media from .mp4 links. Is there a straightforward way to cause these videos to play in a RecyclerView when in the frame? They wouldn't be the only elements in each RecyclerView cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using this library which plays  video as you scroll down just like facebook

[danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager)

Here's a medium article tutorial.
[Implementing video playback in a scrolled list (ListView & RecyclerView)](https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429)